# How to partition a pendrive?

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, acronis-diskdirector

I am using Win 7 RTM, with Acronis Disk Director suit. Is there a way to partition my 4gb pendrive.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Windows won't let you create multiple partitions on a removable drive, which is how a USB flash drive shows up.

For a solution, check out this article :
[Make Windows see any USB flash drive as local disk](http://www.lancelhoff.com/make-windows-see-any-usb-flash-drive-as-local-disk/).
(This article insists a bit too much upon using its own tools. For example, notepad++ is a good tool, but notepad will do as well.)

After going through the above procedure, the USB flash drive should be detected as a local disk, rather than removable, allowing you to partition it from within Windows by using Disk Management.

Comment: good tip, but a security note: this installs a filter driver for your USB pendrive.  does include code, so it might be reasonable, but until audited it should be considered risky.  and a convenience note: you'd need to do this procedure for each drive you want to partition.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion:
http://discussions.virtualdr.com/showthread.php?t=203373

I think this should be moved to superuser, imo.